# Video tag issue in IE9, cannot play MP4 file

Tags: internet-explorer-9, sitecore, mp4

I have use the sub code to play MP4 video in IE9, but failed. What's wrong with my video tag in the ie9?

```
<video class="video-js" width="576" height="324" controls="controls" preload="" poster="~/media/Images/Article/samplevideolarge.ashx?ext=.gif">
<source type="video/mp4; codecs=&quot;avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2&quot;" src="~/media/Files/Videos/sample video mp4.ashx"></source>
<object class="vjs-flash-fallback" width="576" height="324" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="/global/scripts/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf">
 <param name="movie" value="/global/scripts/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf" />
 <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
 <param name="flashvars" value='config={"playlist":["~/media/Images/Article/samplevideolarge.ashx?ext=.gif", {"url": "~/media/Files/Videos/sample video mp4.ashx","autoPlay":false,"autoBuffering":true}]}' />
<!-- Image Fallback. Typically the same as the poster image. -->
<img src="~/media/Images/Article/samplevideolarge.ashx?ext=.gif" width="576" height="324" alt="Poster Image" title="No video playback capabilities." />
</object>
</video>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. I believe the MIME type for mp4 video is `video/mpeg`, not `video/mp4`.
2. I could be mistaken, but I don't think you're supposed to put quotes (or `&quot;`) around codecs.
3. This one may not affect it, but the extension is `.ashx` - I don't know what extension that is, but it might be interfering.

And one more thing, you may want to double-check which specific codecs are supported by IE9.

Comment: The ashx extension is an ASP.NET web handler file, in this instance used by Sitecore to provide media downloads from the database.

Comment: I had this issue as well - using video/mpeg was causing IE9 to fail.  Switched it to video/mp4 based on this resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

Could it have something to do with [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/Wessty/archive/2011/03/13/ie9-and-the-mystery-of-the-broken-video-tag.aspx)? - Just a shot...